# How to trigger language change in ** js year calender** on language change in Angular Application

Tags: angular, ngx-translate

1.I am Using **ngx-translate** from angular to translate application.

2.I am able to change language at initialization option setting.
like `{language:'ja'}` for Japanese inside **jsyearcalender** library.

Any help will be greatly Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Add language like below.

```
 this._translate.use('ja');
 location.reload();
```